# Obter objeto que foi criado no servidor via Angular

Tags: angular, response

Bom dia Pessoal,

Sou iniciante no Angular 4 (utilizando TypesCript) e estou com uma dúvida básica, porém não encontrei resposta por aqui.

Tenho um método typescript que chama um método de uma WebAPI. Esse método da WebAPI cria um objeto e retorna OK(objetoCriado). Não estou conseguindo recuperar os dados do objeto que acabara de ser criado. Eu gostaria de dar um console.log do objeto que criei, mas na primeira vez que salvo, dá undefined e na segunda vez, ele traz o objeto criado anteriormente e não o último.

Sei que é um erro de iniciante na tecnologia, desculpem.

Segue meu código:

WebAPI Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public Professor Create(Professor p)
    {
        //if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        //{
        //    BadRequest();
        //}
        IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IProfessorBLO>().To<ProfessorBLO>();
        IProfessorBLO blo = ninjectKernel.Get<IProfessorBLO>();

        blo.Add(p);

        //return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + p.Id), p);
        return p;
    }
```

Método no TypeScript:

```
  submit(form){
    let professor = form.value.professor;
    let response = this.service.create(form.value.professor);
    console.log(response);
  }
```

Método this.service.create:

```
  create(object){
    this.http.post(this.url,JSON.stringify(object), this.options)
    .subscribe(response=> {
      this.response = response;
    });
    return this.response.json();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja que `this.http.post` é assíncrono, de forma que `this.response` pode não ter o valor retornado pelo servidor quando a função `create` terminar. Uma possível solução seria passar uma função de `callback`, para ser executado quando a resposta vinda do servidor chegar ao cliente.

Método no TypeScript:

```
submit(form){
  let professor = form.value.professor;
  this.service.create(form.value.professor,
    response=> console.log(response));
}
```

Método `this.service.create`:

```
create(object, callback){
  this.http.post(this.url,JSON.stringify(object), this.options)
  .subscribe(response=> {
    this.response = response;
    callback(response);
  });
}
```

Comment: Prezado Marcelo, eu já havia pesado que o posto é assíncrono, mas não tinha ideia de como fazê-lo "esperar" para obter o ID. Como eu usaria essa função de callback (não conheço ainda)?

Comment: Eu entendi sim. Vou usar o callback para obter os dados do professor criado e devolver para a tela. Obrigado.

Comment: Marcelo, ainda tenho uma dúvida. Eu, depois de pegar os dados de volta do servidor, tenho como enviá-los para a tela?
Exemplo: 


  submit(form){
    let response = this.service.create(form.value.professor, 
      (response)=> {
        this.professor = response; 
      });
  }

Do jeito que está acima, os dados vão para a tela?

Comment: OK Marcelo. Já tinha percebido. Eu alterei o código e está funcionando. Estou com outra dúvida, vou criar outro post. Obrigado.